# Socket connection disconnects automatically

Tags: sockets, react-native, socket.io

I am implementing the socket connection for video calling and chat. I am using react-native for client and I use socket.io-client v.2.1.0 and socket.io v.2.1.1 on node server. The socket connection gets established successfully when I open the application but when I lock the phone or the phone sleeps then the socket connection gets disconnected automatically after some time.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `pingTimeout` argument in the socketio docs [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/). Set it to a really high number so the socket doesn't timeout.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this shortly and let you know if the problem still persists.

Comment: I just tried this. I set 6000000 to pingTimeout. The connection stays alive longer than before but still it disconnects within 2-3 minutes. I want to keep it alive until the app is closed or internet disconnects. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I'm bad at formatting. I am trying to post my code but it doesn't formatted properly. Please wait for a while.

Comment: \*Clide side code:\*

`let socket = require('socket.io-client')(config.socketServerUrl, { transports: ['websocket'], jsonp: false, 'forceNew': true });`

Comment: \*Server side code: \*

`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(
    pingTimeout: 6000000,
    pingInterval: 30000
});`

Comment: Why don't you let the socket disconnect and reconnect it when the client and server need to communicate again. It should be more stable.

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement Whatsapp like feature. When the phone is in idle mode for hours or days even that time the user may receive a video call or message. This is why I am trying to do so.

Comment: In case of messages, why don't you try polling? And for calls, try a VoIP library. They should have events and sockets already consutrcted.